# Why is RHEL 6.4 considered beta/pre-release software?

Tags: redhat

I'm new to RHEL and am installing 6.4 for the first time.

The installer refers to it as "beta" and "pre-release" software. Why is that? When I downloaded it from the Red Hat website, nothing indicated that it was a "non-stable" release.

Apologies for the ignorance of this question...

Comment: What makes you think it's pre-release ? Have a link to where you got it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not beta or pre-release, it [has been released](https://www.redhat.com/about/news/press-archive/2013/2/red-hat-announces-general-availability-of-next-minor-release-of-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6) for quite some time now. Do you have a current installer DVD?

Comment: Yep, I downloaded the current installer .iso from their website...

Comment: Apparently I was using the wrong link. Derp.